# get variables from each corresponding columns in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I’d like to obtain three variables from their corresponding columns from the table.

I hope to achieve a similar ouput by using

```
exch product templateID = exec ExchangeID,ProductID,TimeTemplateID from Instruments where InstrumentID=`IF2201
```

Currently I am using one line for each variable:

```
exch= select ExchangeID from Instruments where upper(InstrumentID)==`IF2201
product = select ProductID from Instruments where upper(InstrumentID)==`IF2201
template = select TimeTemplateID from Instruments where upper(InstrumentID)=`IF2201
```

How can I achieve this using only one line of code? Is there any way to simplify the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified to:

```
v = exec exch, product, templateID from t where templateID = "IBM"exch, product, templateID = v[0], v[1], v[2]
```

[image]